# Windows Forms сортировка в listView

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, сортировка

Я имею вот такую часть кода:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   

        FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath))
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(file.ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(file);

            }
            foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(FBD.SelectedPath))
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(item.ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Подскажите, как мне сделать так, чтобы после того как я вывожу содержимое выбранных папок и подпапок в  listView, содержимое можно было сортировать по дате, размеру и типу файлов?

Comment: Google в помощь))) http://www.ishodniki.ru/art/art_progr/net/692.html

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос с примерами кода сортировки есть на сайте майкрсофта:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319401

А вот сдесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548312/sorting-a-listview-by-column

Советуют использовать нестандартный компонент, который значительно удобнее в использовании... В том числе есть возможность сортировки без дополнительного кода.

Линка на сам компонент вот:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx